# Writing big files async or sync in a special thread?

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous, io, hololens

I am recording the screen in Hololens, using C#. I am creating small videos with 100 frames and I plan to write them separately because RAM is not enough to write only one big video.
Which would be better in terms of performance?

Create videos and write them async, or create a work queue that writes them syncronously?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a work queue and only allow 1 (background) thread to write to the same physical disk at the same time.

If you did this with multiple threads to a spinning disk, each thread would be fighting for access, causing a lot of unnecessary disk seeks and switching between threads/files.

On average, a disk seek is around 10ms (to 15ms). In that same time an extra megabyte could have been written.

So, for spinning disks, writing from multiple threads will never be faster (but probably slower, depending on the buffering/caching).

For SSD however there *could* be some speed improvement - but there is always a maximum total bandwidth. So if the data to be written is ready in memory, writing from a single thread should be close to the available SSD bandwidth.

Comment: I am using Microsoft hololens. The best i could find about the type of memory is flash memory from wikipedia page. Also, can you provide me with some help how to create a background non blocking queue thread?